# Why do people use RaiseError instead of Print in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tried both the below queries and they perform in same time. But still I have seen RaiseError used in many stored procedures instead of print.

**Query 1:**

```
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.00'

    PRINT 'DELAY 1 HAS ENDED'

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.00'

    PRINT 'DELAY 2 HAS ENDED'
END
```

**Query 2:**

```
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.00'

    RAISERROR ('DELAY 1 HAS ENDED', 10,1) WITH NOWAIT

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.00'

    RAISERROR ('DELAY 2 HAS ENDED', 10,1) WITH NOWAIT

END
```

Both give the desired output only after 6 seconds (I have checked this in SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same server version as you did, and Query 2 prints the first result after 3 seconds (as expected). You have to switch to the Message tab on your own in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to see the message.

Comment: +1 The messages tab doesn't get switched to automatically until the query ends at 6 seconds but `RAISERROR` still prints the first message there after 3 seconds. Tested on 2008 R2.

Comment: Change your result output to Results to Text instead of Results to Grid. The latter only displays the message after, the former is immediate. If you run queries with NOWAIT from sqlcmd command line you will also see that they are immediate.

Answer (score 13):

The advantage of `RAISERROR` over `PRINT` is that you may embed variables values within the message without having to bother with `CAST`and `CONVERT`.
For instance:

```
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @m INT = 0

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.00'
     SET @m += 1;
     RAISERROR ('DELAY %d HAS ENDED', 10, 1, @m)
 
     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.00'     
     SET @m += 1;
     RAISERROR ('DELAY %d HAS ENDED', 10, 1, @m)
 
 END
```

This will produce same output in both examples above, except it will insert the value of variable into the message. With a `PRINT` you have to do:

```
PRINT 'DELAY ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @m) + ' HAS ENDED'
```

...which is possible but cumbersome...

Comment: Another advantage of `RAISERROR` is that you may add the `WITH NOWAIT` option: then you get the message immediately in sqlserver management studio Message tab, and you don't have to wait for the message buffer to fill-up: that's useful in long-running queries.
True that one may not see the effect of `WITH NOWAIT` in short queries, below ~30 seconds. True also that after some time the effect of `WITH NOWAIT`  ends and the output is bufferred again (~50 Kb of messages).  
This doesn't affect behaviour of SQLCMD, though...

Answer (score 2):

There is a return statement buffer that causes `PRINT` statements to only flush when full (or SQL Server deigns to do so). `RAISERROR(x, y, z) WITH NOWAIT` either does not use that buffer or appears to force a flush of that buffer after adding its message.

Other than this and the embedded variable behavior mentioned by Philippe in his answer, there appears to be no real functional difference between low-severity `RAISERROR` and `PRINT`.

Here's a short 2018 post by Louis Davidson (@drsql) with more code samples and links to other posts with even more detail on this: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/outputting-status-t-sql-code/.

As for me, I now use `RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 42) WITH NOWAIT` for my batch script progress outputs after getting frustrated waiting for `PRINT` statements to come through.

Answer (score 1):

We use RAISERROR to track actual errors a bit easier.  This comes in handy since you can set severity for items and you can see the results right away in the Messages section.

PRINT is used for a really cheap/quick debugger in a multi-step process that shows how far we actually get when I don't actually expect immediate feedback.