# Is there a better logging alternative than RAISEERROR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using `RAISEERROR` in my database scripts to log informational messages.

```sql
DECLARE @totalrows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable);
DECLARE @fancyrows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE fancy = 1);
RAISEERROR ('%i rows out of %i are fancy', 10, 1, @fancyrows, @totalrows) WITH NOWAIT;
-- Do some more things...
```

Using a severity parameter lower than `11` means it won't stop the execution of the script, but my co-worker pointed out that when reading the script, it does still seem to imply something has gone wrong.

Is there a clearer way of logging informational messages in SQL? Something like `LOGMESSAGE` for example?

Comment: Maybe relevant [Why do people use RaiseError instead of Print in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666593/why-do-people-use-raiseerror-instead-of-print-in-t-sql)

Comment: It only implies something has gone wrong to people that aren't aware that severity of 10 or less are info messages rather than error messages. So you can educate your co worker on this and problem solved. 

In some cases you can use `PRINT CONCAT()` to replace the string interpolation but this still won't allow you to specify `NOWAIT`.

There is no equivalent function that avoids the word "error" - I guess you could replace the `10` with a variable called `@INFO_SEVERITY` or something

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . It is called `RAISE**ERROR**()` so that isn't such an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: yeah it's not unreasonable until you are told. But once you are told then you learned something and now you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give this question an answer (based on [@Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte)'s [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11666593/13762264) & [@Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)'s comment):

**`RAISEERROR` is the most powerful method of logging in SQL Server.** There is a `PRINT` method that is functionally similar but falls short on a couple of points. The advantages of `RAISEERROR` are:

- Natively allows string interpolation.
- Can be used with `WITH NOWAIT` causing its output to be logged immediately. This is not true for `PRINT` which uses a message buffer that can delay its output